# How to select multiple class class with same name in JS

Tags: javascript, php

I use PHP to dynamically render these lists that I fetched from the database, and each one has the same class, because I can't change it, it renders dynamically.  I select these classes via JavaScript and create an event on click to open and close them with the hidden class.

Now I have a problem, this event works for me and reacts only for the first rendered list, but not for the others.  Is there any way to do this, I tried querySelectorAll and getElementsByClassName and some other selectors but nothing worked.
**PHP Code:**

```
<ul class="kartonul">
                        <?php
                         $user = get_user(); 
                         $user_id = $user['id'];
                             $query = "SELECT * FROM karton WHERE id_pacijent = $user_id";
                             $result = query($query);
                         
                             if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                 
                                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                     $karton = get_karton($user_id); 
                                     foreach($result as $karton) { 
                                      echo "<li class='likarton'>Karton " .$karton['id']." <i class='fa-solid fa-envelope'></i></li>
                                        <div  class='kartondiv hiddenRaspored'>
                                        <label class='kartonlabel'>Nalaz:</label> <br/>
                                        <p>" . $karton['nalaz'] . "</p>
                                        <label class='kartonlabel'>Dijagnoza:</label> <br/>
                                        <p>" . $karton['dijagnoza'] . "</p>
                                        <label class='kartonlabel'>Pregled:</label> <br/>
                                        <p>" . $karton['pregled'] . "</p>
                                        </div>";
                                     }
                                 }
                                }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
let karton = document.querySelector('.likarton');
let div = document.querySelector('.kartondiv');

karton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (div.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    div.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    div.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

**This is a template:**
[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r9vp.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvBwS.png)

Comment: The PHP doesn't seem to have anything to do with your problem. As such, please show the rendered html, not the PHP.

Comment: html is in echo

Comment: I know that. Please run the PHP in your browser, then paste the **rendered** html in your question.

Comment: oke, i did now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only selecting the first `.likarton` instance - this is fixed by using `querySelectorAll()`

---

Since you are using `addEventListener`, you are getting the exact item being clicked as an argument into the callback.

The correct javascript to use this feature is `addEventListener('click', (event) => {})`

And to reference the element on which the event handler was fired, you can use `event.currentTarget`

From that point, you can select the div and use `.classList.*` to modify the class list

---

example

```js
let karton = document.querySelectorAll('.likarton');

for (let i = 0; i < karton.length; i++) {
  karton[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let div = document.querySelector('.kartondiv');

    if (div.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      div.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      div.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
}
```

---

refs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll#syntax

Comment: @eld4rr are you sure you're using the code in a similar fashion as I have in my example? this code works on 4 different browsers I've tested on

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `querySelectorAll()` instead of `querySelector()`.

This way you will target all of the elements instead of the first one matching.
You should then loop through each one and add an event listener like this:

```
let kartons  = document.querySelectorAll(".abc");

kartons.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
         // Something happens on click

    })
});
```

Comment: That probably means inside your karton variable is not of EventTarget data type. I would try console.log(karton) to see what's inside.

Comment: Are you sure you are working with the name of a variable you specified within the forEach() function? I named it as "el" so if you did not rename it, you should use el.addEventListener() or console.log(el). 

If your problem persists, send me a working demo so I can help you easily.

Comment: Please put your demo to some online editor like https://jsfiddle.net or Codepen